# Node.js Express nested resources

Tags: node.js, rest, express, nested

i'd like to nest resources like the below eg.

```
/// fileA.js
app.use('/dashboards/:dashboard_id/teams', teams);
[...]

///teams.js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
[...]
}
```

but I can't get the req.params["dashboard_id"] parameter in *teams* because it seems it is already substituted with the parameter value.
I've tried to baypass the problem by calling an intermediate function and pass somewhere the parameter but I can't figure out where ...
Do you have an answer?
Thanks,
Franco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this solution:

```
//declare a function that will pass primary router's params to the request
var passPrimaryParams = function(req, res, next) {
    req.primaryParams = req.params;
    next();
}

/// fileA.js
app.use('/dashboards/:dashboard_id/teams', passPrimaryParams);
app.use('/dashboards/:dashboard_id/teams', teams);

///teams.js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var dashboardId = req.primaryParams['dashboard_id'];  //should work now
    //here you may also use req.params -- current router's params
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Express 4.0.0 or above at the time of this writing:

To make the router understand nested resources with variables you will need create and bind a new router using `app.use` for every base path.

```
//creates a new router
var dashboardRouter = express.router();

//bind your route
dashboardRouter.get("/:dashboard_id/teams", teams);

//bind to application router
app.use('/dashboards', dashboardRouter);
```

This way Express will see the first part of the path and go to the `/dashboards` route, which has the `:dashboard_id/teams` path.

Comment: This will require us to bind a route for each route in the parent router, which is not ideal. Much better to use router.use if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mergeParams` option here

```
// fileA.js
app.use('/dashboards/:dashboard_id/teams', teams);

// teams.js
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // you will have access to req.params.dashboard_id here
}
```

You can also see this answer: [Rest with Express.js nested router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260818/rest-with-express-js-nested-router)