# Rest with Express.js nested router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose I want to have REST endpoints which look roughly like this:

```
/user/
/user/user_id 

/user/user_id/items/
/user/user_id/items/item_id
```

CRUD on each if makes sense. For example, /user POST creates a new user, GET fetches all users. /user/*user_id* GET fetches just that one user.

Items are user specific so I put them under *user_id*, which is a particular user.

Now to make Express routing modular I made a few router instances. There is a router for user, and a router for the item.

```
var userRouter = require('express').Router();
userRouter.route('/')
  .get(function() {})
  .post(function() {})
userRouter.route('/:user_id')
  .get(function() {})

var itemRouter = require('express').Router();
itemRouter.route('/')
  .get(function() {})
  .post(function() {})
itemRouter.route('/:item_id')
  .get(function() {})

app.use('/users', userRouter);

// Now how to add the next router?
// app.use('/users/', itemRouter);
```

URL to `item` is descendents of the URL hierarchy of the `user`. Now how do I get URL with `/users` whatever to userRouter but the more specific route of `/user/*user_id*/items/` to the itemRouter? And also, I would like user_id to be accessible to itemRouter as well, if possible.

Comment: Great answers already on using Express to solve this. You could, however, use Loopback (built on Express) to implement a Swagger-based API and add relations between models to perform the CRUD like you asked. Nice thing is after initial learning curve, it is much faster to assemble. http://loopback.io/

Answer (score 407, accepted):

You can nest routers by attaching them as [middleware](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) on an other router, with or without `params`.

You must pass `{mergeParams: true}` to the child router if you want to access the `params` from the parent router.

`mergeParams` was introduced in [Express `4.5.0`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/releases/tag/4.5.0) (Jul 5 2014)

In this example the `itemRouter` gets attached to the `userRouter` on the `/:userId/items` route

This will result in following possible routes:

`GET /user` -> `hello user`
`GET /user/5` -> `hello user 5`
`GET /user/5/items` -> `hello items from user 5`
`GET /user/5/items/6` -> `hello item 6 from user 5`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var userRouter = express.Router();
// you need to set mergeParams: true on the router,
// if you want to access params from the parent router
var itemRouter = express.Router({mergeParams: true});

// you can nest routers by attaching them as middleware:
userRouter.use('/:userId/items', itemRouter);

userRouter.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.status(200)
            .send('hello users');
    });

userRouter.route('/:userId')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.status(200)
            .send('hello user ' + req.params.userId);
    });

itemRouter.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.status(200)
            .send('hello items from user ' + req.params.userId);
    });

itemRouter.route('/:itemId')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.status(200)
            .send('hello item ' + req.params.itemId + ' from user ' + req.params.userId);
    });

app.use('/user', userRouter);

app.listen(3003);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The router you uses here is more explicitly nested than the one shared by Jordonias. But does it works the same underneath the hood? I would like to grant you the bounty for comprehensiveness but I cannot do it until a few hours later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a similar way to get from the child route the **query** params of the parent route?

Comment: It would surprise me if they aren't available on any route, as the query param aren't tied to any route in specific...

Comment: Very thorough answer! One question: for the sake of encapsulation and separation of knowledge between the user router and the item router is there a declarative way to specify that a subrouter requires a parameter? In other words, is there an explicit way to write the registration or access calls such that the item router lets us know it expects to be passed a user id? Example situation, the item router is in another file altogether, structurally it isn't clear that it requires a user unless you get into its calls and it's only clear in the user router that it would pass a user id

Comment: This is no more legible that "standard" use of routers, I'm looking for a way to visualize the nesting when viewing the code.

Comment: for some reason, route.route('/') is not needed, its just route.get / route.post

Answer (score 183):

## manageable nested routes...

I wanted a specific example of doing nested routes in a very manageable way in express 4 and this was the top search result for "nested routes in express". Here's an API that would have many routes that would need to be broken up for example.

**./index.js:**

```
var app = require('express')();

// anything beginning with "/api" will go into this
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

app.listen(3000);
```

**./routes/api/index.js:**

```
var router = require('express').Router();

// split up route handling
router.use('/products', require('./products'));
router.use('/categories', require('./categories'));
// etc.

module.exports = router;
```

**./routes/api/products.js:**

```
var router = require('express').Router();

// api/products
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ products: [] });
});

// api/products/:id
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ id: req.params.id });
});

module.exports = router;
```

### Nesting example in folder structure

I noticed some comments on "nesting folder structure". It is implied in this however not obvious so I added the section below. Here's a specific example of a **nested folder structure for routes**.

```
index.js
/api
  index.js
  /admin
    index.js
    /users
      index.js
      list.js
    /permissions
      index.js
      list.js
```

This is more a general example of how node works. If you use "index.js" in folders similarly to how "index.html" works in web pages for a directory default, this will be easy to scale your organization based off of recursion without changing your entry points to code. "index.js" is the default document accessed when using **require** in a directory.

**contents of index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/api', require('./api'));
module.exports = router;
```

**contents of /api/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/admin', require('./admin'));
module.exports = router;
```

**contents of /api/admin/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/users', require('./users'));
router.use('/permissions', require('./permissions'));
module.exports = router;
```

**contents of /api/admin/users/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', require('./list'));
module.exports = router;
```

There is some DRY issues here possibly but it does lend itself well to encapsulation of concerns.

FYI, recently I got into actionhero and have found it to be full featured w/sockets and tasks, more like a true framework all-in-one flipping the REST paradigm on its head. You should probably check it out over going naked w/ express.

Comment: I see how this splits up the routes, but how does it address nesting?

Comment: perfect....and makes sense. This is a scalable option. I would be curious to know how the op will implement versioning (v1, v2 etc)

Comment: 5 years later and still looks pretty good thank you!

Answer (score 10):

```
var userRouter = require('express').Router();
var itemRouter = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true }); 

userRouter.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {})
  .post(function(req, res) {})
userRouter.route('/:user_id')
  .get(function() {})

itemRouter.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {})
  .post(function(req, res) {})
itemRouter.route('/:item_id')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    return res.send(req.params);
  });

app.use('/user/', userRouter);
app.use('/user/:user_id/item', itemRouter);
```

The key to the second part of your question is the use of the mergeParams option

```
var itemRouter = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

From `/user/jordan/item/cat` I get a reponse:

```
{"user_id":"jordan","item_id":"cat"}
```

Comment: Cool. Both yours and Willem's method works for what I wanted. I'll check his for comprehensiveness but I'll mark you up as well. Thanks a lot. Your method doesn't look nested but it pretty much does what I wanted I think I even prefer yours. Thanks.

Comment: the mergeParams option is key here!

Answer (score 8):

In the spirit of Express modular routers, we should have a separate router for users and for items. That router isn't part of our top-level application logic. We can nest it in our users' router instead.

**Users router**

```
const users = require('express').Router();
const items = require('./items');

//...

// Our root route to /users
albums.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // res.send() our response here
});

// A route to handle requests to any individual user, identified by an user id
users.get('/:userId', function(req, res, next) {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  // retrieve user from database using userId
  // res.send() response with user data
});

// Note, this route represents /users/:userId/items because our top-level router is already forwarding /users to our Users router!
users.use('/:userId/items', items);

//...

module.exports = users;
```

**Items router**

```
// We need to merge params to make userId available in our Items router
const items = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });

//...

// The root router for requests to our items path
items.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let userId = req.params.userId; // Here is where mergeParams makes its magic

  // retrieve user's track data and render items list page
});

// The route for handling a request to a specific item
items.get('/:itemId', function(req, res, next) {
  let userId = req.params.userId; // <-- mergeParams magic
  let itemId = req.params.itemId;

  // retrieve individual item data and render on single item page
});

//...

module.exports = items;
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/f38b208a492e4dcd45f487638eff716c)

Answer (score 7):

Using @Jason Sebring solution, and adapting for Typescript.

**server.ts**

```
import Routes from './api/routes';
app.use('/api/', Routes);
```

**/api/routes/index.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import HomeRoutes from './home';

const router = Router();

router.use('/', HomeRoutes);
// add other routes...

export default router;
```

**/api/routes/home.ts**

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Welcome to API',
  });
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Could you provide `./api/routes`?

Comment: @Julian: I've fixed file locations. `./api/routes` has two files `index.ts` and `home.ts`. The first one is used by `server.ts`. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

try to add  `{ mergeParams: true }` look to simple example  which it middleware use it in controller file `getUser` at the same for  `postUser`

```
const userRouter = require("express").Router({ mergeParams: true });
export default ()=>{
  userRouter
    .route("/")
    .get(getUser)
    .post(postUser);

  userRouter.route("/:user_id").get(function () {});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Express router(express.Router()) keeps params seprate so you would explicitly have to tell express to merge these params.
eg:
express.Router({ mergeParams: true })

//above line is answer to your question.

Answer (score -12):

You need only one router, and use it like this:

```
router.get('/users');
router.get('/users/:user_id');

router.get('/users/:user_id/items');
router.get('/users/:user_id/items/:item_id');

app.use('api/v1', router);
```

Comment: Yes but I want to separate the logics between the items and the users, and so I prefer to separate them though. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @huggie `items` belong to `users` right, why do you need to seperate that? you can define them in different files still using the same router if you want that.

Comment: It belongs to user but I want to be able to easily plug it in or out without effecting user. And currently I have each router for a different URL endpoints. The style seems to be encouraged by express-generator. If it's not possible, then yeah maybe I should send the router instance to different files? But that's not consistent to the original structures.

Comment: Is it possible to add one router underneath another? Since Express middleware architecture seems to be handled by router underneath (I'm not entirely sure if it is) I think it could be possible.

Comment: I don't know i've never seen such a thing. It's interesting though.

Comment: -1 This is not answering the question that is about nested routers

Comment: @facebook It's OK we all learn something new. The other two answers provided by Jordanias and Willem both do what I wanted.

Comment: This doesn't specifically answer the question however, it suggests an alternative solution to the problem. I like the idea. +1 for that reason. ty.