# HapiJS: Nested routes and views

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Is it possible to configure nested routes/views with HapiJS?

For example if we navigate to the following route it would display a list of movies:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/movies',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        return reply.view('movies', {
            data: MOVIES_LIST
        });
    }
}
```

When we select a movie from that list we navigate to the following route:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/movies/{movie_id}',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        return reply.view('movie', {
            data: SELECTED_MOVIE
        });
    }
}
```

Then we should render the movie view as nested from the movies route.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with the code above?

Comment: You can access the {movie_id} param in your handler by using: request.params.movie_id. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood. My question is about nested views with HapiJS view system. I have updated the original question by adding an example, please take a look.

Comment: Question looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/29143194/946789