# How to pass path parameters to a sub router in Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

For the code below:

```
router.use('/campaigns/:campaign_uid', cache.node_cache, api_dynamic_campaign.router);
```

I have a router route to another router which looks like this:

```
router.get('/data.json', campaigns);
```

The handler looks like this:

```
function campaigns(request, response){
    var campaign = api.get_campaign_from_request(request) || request.params.campaign_uid;
    api.route_handler(request, response, {"campaign":campaign});
}
```

My issue is the handler does not have access to campaign_uid in the request.params.
How do I access/pass the campaign_uid to the handler?

Comment: Your middleware can add properties to the `req` object and those properties will be accessible to other route handlers down the chain.  That's what lots of middleware handlers already do for things like cookies and query parameters, etc...

Comment: I believe that this is what app.param or router.param is meant for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rest with Express.js nested router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260818/rest-with-express-js-nested-router)

Answer (score 3):

```
router.get('/data.json', campaigns).Router({ mergeParams: true })
```

https://cedric.tech/blog/expressjs-accessing-req-params-from-child-routers

Comment: Please take some time in actually explaining the content of your answer. Sometimes it can be helpful to post external references, but that's only a good top up to an already very exhaustive answer