# How to create nested routes with parameters using NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I need to build an API where most of the routes are prefixed with a common URL part which also has a parameter.

In my specific case, my routes need to look like:

`/accounts/:account/resource1/:someParam`

`/accounts/:account/resource2/:someParam/whatever`

`/accounts/:account/resource3/`

`/accounts/:account/resource4/subResource/`

and so on..

So ideally I would create a *parent* route `/accounts/:account/` which will contain the *children* routes (`resource1`, `resource2`, `resource3`, `resource4`, etc...).

I also need the `:account` parameter to be accessible from all the children routes.

What is the best way to achieve this with NestJS ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260818/rest-with-express-js-nested-router

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module

Answer (score 22):

i think you need this?

```
import {Controller, Get, Param} from "@nestjs/common";

@Controller('accounts/:account')
export class TestController{

    @Get('resource2/:someParam/whatever')
    arsPW(@Param('account') account, @Param('someParam') someparam){
        console.log(':account/resource2/:someParam/whatever',account,someparam)
        return account+'_'+someparam+'___';
    }

    @Get('resource1/:someparam')
    aRSP(@Param('account') account, @Param('someparam') someparam){
        console.log(':account/resource1/:someParam',account,someparam)
        return account+'_'+someparam;
    }


    @Get()
    getget(){
        console.log('get');
        return 'aaa';
    }

}
```

Comment: this is what I'm currently using, but what if I have many children routes? I don't want to have a single, fat Controller class. Ideally I would be able to create different child routes inside different Controller classes

Comment: I have kind of the same controller file. But I am not able to call this API. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22):

Regarding your use case, you might want to take a look at this router module

=> https://github.com/shekohex/nest-router

Following the documentation of this module, you can define your routes like so:

```
... //imports
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '/ninja',
      module: NinjaModule,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/cats',
          module: CatsModule,
        },
        {
          path: '/dogs',
          module: DogsModule,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

@Module({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoutes(routes), // setup the routes
      CatsModule,
      DogsModule,
      NinjaModule
      ], // as usual, nothing new
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

Of course, the routes would be defined in a separate file like `routes.ts`

Given the fact you have a controller by module, the previous code would end in the following tree of routes:

```
ninja
    ├── /
    ├── /katana
    ├── cats
    │   ├── /
    │   └── /ketty
    ├── dogs
        ├── /
        └── /puppy
```

***Example***:
If you want to reach the *`ketty`* controller's routes, you will need to reach this endpoint: 
**`<your-api-host>/ninja/cats/ketty`**

---

**Update**
This approach is outdated today if you using NestJs `v8.0.0` or later, as the documentation of [nest-router](https://github.com/shekohex/nest-router) tells us it's now included on `@nestjs/core`

and also as pointed by @yehonatan yehezkel, you can follow the documentation for the recommended approach at here https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module

Comment: I think this do not answer this requirement "I also need the :account parameter to be accessible from all the children routes.".

Comment: Check out the part about nested route:
https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-router#params-in-nested-routes

Comment: this way is not recommended by nestjs docs because it became to complex to mantain
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module

Answer (score 15):

Parent controller :

```
@Controller('accounts')
export class AccountsController {
  // http://api.domaine.com/accounts
  @Get()
```

Child controller :

```
@Controller('accounts/:id')
export class ResourcesController {
  // http://api.domaine.com/accounts/1/resources
  @Get('resources')
```

Comment: ...and then how you get :id from that second example?

Comment: method(@param('id') id)

Comment: This is the pattern I'm using, and it's the best I've seen, but it's still not great for an enterprise API. If you then want to have `/resources/:id`, you need to define another `ResourcesController`, perhaps renaming the one above to `AccountsResourcesController` to make 'space'. I wish there were a mechanism to annotate a class method to ignore the parent controller route / override it. If anyone spots this and finds a better way, please let me know!

Comment: @mikey I think use router module might work https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module

Comment: I have been wondering about the case, where :id for the accounts is not required. e.g. there is a relationship between accounts and resources but I want to get all resources. I would like to have a route: /accounts/resources but it appears that NestJS routes this to /accounts/:id instead.

Answer (score 5):

you can simply do this

```
@Controller('trainer/:trainerId/heroes')
 export class HeroesController {
    constructor(private readonly heroesService: HeroesService) {}

    @Get(':id')
    findOne(@Param('trainerId') trainerId:string,@Param('id') id: string) {
       return `This action returns a #${id} hero trainer id ${trainerId}`;
    }

 }
```

the uri is:

```
http://localhost:3000/trainer/4/heroes/5
```

thr result is

```
This action returns a #5 hero trainer id 4
```