# How would you pass something to a router?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I've been working on an endpoint but I want it to work like `bot/:id/vote`

How would I get the ID to pass into that router so it goes like `https://example.com/bot/512333785338216465/vote`

#### Code

```js
const vote = require("../routers/voting");
app.use("/bot/:id/vote", vote);
```

Comment: `req.params.id`

Comment: @hoangdv I tried that `req.params` becomes `{}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260818/rest-with-express-js-nested-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `mergeParams(default: false)` option when creates a new router object.

> Preserve the `req.params` values from the parent router. If the parent and the child have conflicting param names, the child’s value take precedence.

So the working code is:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Router } = express;

const vote = Router({ mergeParams: true });
vote.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params); //=> { id: '512333785338216465' }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.use('/bot/:id/vote', vote);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started at http://localhost:3000'));
```

package version: `"express": "^4.17.1",`

Comment: Thank you, this was wrecking my brain for days lol.