# NodeJS Express recursive routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

Some website's APIs let you do something like this:

```
            Initial user's id          their first friend, also a user
                 v                     v
GET /api/users/54282/friends/0/friends/0
                             ^
                        first item in array, would also be a user
```

Rather than

```
            Initial user's id
                 v
GET /api/users/54282/friends
Look at friends[0].id to get the first friend's id

            First friend's id
                 v
GET /api/users/97420/friends
Look at friends[0].id to get the first friend's id

            First friend's id
                 v
GET /api/users/31230
```

Another example although i'm not sure if Github allows this

```
Get the 10th collaborator's repos
GET /api/users/sharedrory/repos/312388/collaborators/10/repos
```

How do would you implement something like this in express?

Comment: The inefficient way to implement it is to query each time you get a request and return just the index of the requested item.  The efficient way would involve some sort of query cache so subsequent requests don't have to rerun the query every time.

Comment: Or, some databases will have a way to query for a specific index range and leave the caching to the database itself.

Comment: More typical in API design is an ability for a client to request a range of values and receive a chunk of results back.  You never want a client making separate requests for the 0th item, then the 1st item, then the 2nd item and so on as that's very inefficient use of the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 If I wanted all the item in the array, I wouldn't append /<index>. Instead, I want say friends of a user's first friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the term I wanted was "nested"/"nesting"

[Rest with Express.js nested router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260818/rest-with-express-js-nested-router)
https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/f38b208a492e4dcd45f487638eff716c